# how to change browserSync Port

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

My application is running on port 8000. I have changed the borowserSync port to 8000 from browser-sync/default-config.js. And it looks something like this

```
// Change the default project
ui: {
    port: 8000
},

ui: {
    port: 8000,
    weinre: {
        port: 8000
    }
},
```

but when I ran gulp watch command it spins the server on port 8001. 
my terminal looks like this after I ran gulp watch command

```
[23:40:54] Starting 'browserSync'...
[23:40:54] Finished 'browserSync' after 23 ms
[23:40:54] Starting 'sass'...
[BS] Access URLs:
------------------------------------
Local: http://localhost:8001
External: http://192.168.1.6:8001
------------------------------------
UI: http://localhost:8002
UI External: http://192.168.1.6:8002
```

Does anyone know who to change the port in browserSync.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of shifting by 1 normally happens when there is something else running on the port. Do you have another instance that is already occupying port 8000?

I notice that you have port 8000 mentioned twice in your config file and you have two of the same node for ui

My config for gulp looks like this for example

```
browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
  startPath: '/',
  ui: {
    port: 3001
  },
  server: server, //server variable set elsewhere
  port: 3000,
  browser: browser, //set elsewhere
});
```

So your config should look more like

```
{
  port: 8000,//Or whatever port you want for your application
  ui: {
    port: 8001 //Or whatever port you want for browsersync ui
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right. My development server is running on port 8000. As soon as i stopped it. Browser sync started taking port 8000 but my application stopped working. Is there a way to keep both running on 8000 simultaneously.

Comment: @vsoni, You can never have more than one application on any given port. That is a fundamental when it comes to ports. You can just run the ui on a different port then access with localhost:8001 for example. PS please accept the (updated answer) if it solves your issue :)